# Есть дерево объектов, нужно изменить названия ключей

Tags: javascript, дерево

Есть такой массив:

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "site_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "parent_id": null,
    "lft": 1,
    "rgt": 12,
    "depth": 0,
    "slug": "9759",
    "external_id": null,
    "preview_image": null,
    "description_image": null,
    "title": "Категория",
    "preview": null,
    "description": null,
    "og_title": null,
    "og_description": null,
    "m_title": null,
    "m_description": null,
    "m_keywords": null,
    "s_keywords": null,
    "created_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
    "updated_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "site_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "lft": 2,
        "rgt": 7,
        "depth": 1,
        "slug": "6630",
        "external_id": null,
        "preview_image": null,
        "description_image": null,
        "title": "Под категория",
        "preview": null,
        "description": null,
        "og_title": null,
        "og_description": null,
        "m_title": null,
        "m_description": null,
        "m_keywords": null,
        "s_keywords": null,
        "created_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "site_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "lft": 3,
            "rgt": 4,
            "depth": 2,
            "slug": "5322",
            "external_id": null,
            "preview_image": null,
            "description_image": null,
            "title": "Под под категория",
            "preview": null,
            "description": null,
            "og_title": null,
            "og_description": null,
            "m_title": null,
            "m_description": null,
            "m_keywords": null,
            "s_keywords": null,
            "created_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
            "updated_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "site_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "lft": 5,
            "rgt": 6,
            "depth": 2,
            "slug": "8655",
            "external_id": null,
            "preview_image": null,
            "description_image": null,
            "title": "Под под категория 2",
            "preview": null,
            "description": null,
            "og_title": null,
            "og_description": null,
            "m_title": null,
            "m_description": null,
            "m_keywords": null,
            "s_keywords": null,
            "created_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
            "updated_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "site_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "lft": 8,
        "rgt": 9,
        "depth": 1,
        "slug": "8430",
        "external_id": null,
        "preview_image": null,
        "description_image": null,
        "title": "Под категория 2",
        "preview": null,
        "description": null,
        "og_title": null,
        "og_description": null,
        "m_title": null,
        "m_description": null,
        "m_keywords": null,
        "s_keywords": null,
        "created_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "site_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "lft": 10,
        "rgt": 11,
        "depth": 1,
        "slug": "7262",
        "external_id": null,
        "preview_image": null,
        "description_image": null,
        "title": "Под категория 3",
        "preview": null,
        "description": null,
        "og_title": null,
        "og_description": null,
        "m_title": null,
        "m_description": null,
        "m_keywords": null,
        "s_keywords": null,
        "created_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-15 16:54:56",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Нужно привести его к такому виду (при помощи javascript)

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Категория",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Под категория",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "label": "Под под категория",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "label": "Под под категория 2",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "label": "Под категория 2",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "label": "Под категория 3",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вроде несложный рекурсивный обход?

```js
var data = {"1":{"id":1,"deleted_at":null,"site_id":1,"user_id":1,"parent_id":null,"lft":1,"rgt":12,"depth":0,"slug":"9759","external_id":null,"preview_image":null,"description_image":null,"title":"Категория","preview":null,"description":null,"og_title":null,"og_description":null,"m_title":null,"m_description":null,"m_keywords":null,"s_keywords":null,"created_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","updated_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","children":[{"id":2,"deleted_at":null,"site_id":1,"user_id":1,"parent_id":1,"lft":2,"rgt":7,"depth":1,"slug":"6630","external_id":null,"preview_image":null,"description_image":null,"title":"Под категория","preview":null,"description":null,"og_title":null,"og_description":null,"m_title":null,"m_description":null,"m_keywords":null,"s_keywords":null,"created_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","updated_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","children":[{"id":3,"deleted_at":null,"site_id":1,"user_id":1,"parent_id":2,"lft":3,"rgt":4,"depth":2,"slug":"5322","external_id":null,"preview_image":null,"description_image":null,"title":"Под под категория","preview":null,"description":null,"og_title":null,"og_description":null,"m_title":null,"m_description":null,"m_keywords":null,"s_keywords":null,"created_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","updated_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","children":[]},{"id":4,"deleted_at":null,"site_id":1,"user_id":1,"parent_id":2,"lft":5,"rgt":6,"depth":2,"slug":"8655","external_id":null,"preview_image":null,"description_image":null,"title":"Под под категория 2","preview":null,"description":null,"og_title":null,"og_description":null,"m_title":null,"m_description":null,"m_keywords":null,"s_keywords":null,"created_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","updated_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","children":[]}]},{"id":5,"deleted_at":null,"site_id":1,"user_id":1,"parent_id":1,"lft":8,"rgt":9,"depth":1,"slug":"8430","external_id":null,"preview_image":null,"description_image":null,"title":"Под категория 2","preview":null,"description":null,"og_title":null,"og_description":null,"m_title":null,"m_description":null,"m_keywords":null,"s_keywords":null,"created_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","updated_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","children":[]},{"id":6,"deleted_at":null,"site_id":1,"user_id":1,"parent_id":1,"lft":10,"rgt":11,"depth":1,"slug":"7262","external_id":null,"preview_image":null,"description_image":null,"title":"Под категория 3","preview":null,"description":null,"og_title":null,"og_description":null,"m_title":null,"m_description":null,"m_keywords":null,"s_keywords":null,"created_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","updated_at":"2018-02-15 16:54:56","children":[]}]}};






function map(obj){
   return { 
         id: obj.id,
         label: obj.title, 
         children: obj.children.map(map)
      } ;
}

var result = map(data[1]);


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!))

Comment: @WebMaster упростил код еще немного

Comment: teran, спасибо очень помогли весь день протупил, нужно было сразу вопрос задавать))